# Using onClick While Making a Health Bar (Game)

Tags: javascript

**Hello! This is my first post so my sincere apologies if it's been already asked and I haven't looked thoroughly enough to find it.**

---

I have a question regarding a game I am creating. It is using a div where when you click it, it reduces the enemy's HP. I have that part down and good, but I want a way to display it on an HP bar.

So lets say you click on the enemy a couple ties and it loses 50 HP. I want a HP bar below showing the rest of HP it has left. So I click it and it has 25 HP, then It would show 25/ (Lets just say in total) 100 HP.

I am also wondering how you would use color too. Like in the game Pokémon, once you go under 50% HP, your bar turns slightly yellow, then orange, then red. 

Thanks for all your help and I hope you have a wonderful day!

```js
const player = {
    name:"none",
    hp: 50,
    atk: 5
};

player.name = prompt("Welcome Warrior, what is your name?");
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Private, " + player.name;

const enemy = {
    hp: 50
};

const hitMe = (hitPoint) => {
    enemy.hp = enemy.hp - hitPoint;
    console.log(enemy.hp);
    console.log(player);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTPYE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css">
        
    </head>
        
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="display">
                <div  id="info">
                    <div id="char">
                        <div class="box" id="name"></div>
                        <div class="box" id="weapon">Weapon</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box" id="hp">Health</div>
                </div>
                <div class="box" id="shop">Shop</div>
            </div>
            <div id="holder">
                <div class="box" id="enemybox" onclick="hitMe(3)">
                    monster
                </div>
                <div class="box" id="enemyhp">
                    Health
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <script src="game.js"></script>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: even though you're changing it later, why is `enemy`'s object `const`?

Comment: can you use a simple <meter> or <progress> or <input type=range> tag?

Answer (score 1):

As for the HP bar goes, you will have to know what is the maximum HP of the enemy. For this you need another variable say `maxHP`. I will be adding this to `enemy`'s object and removing the `const` constraint since you're changing its values in `hitMe`.

```
enemy = {
    hp:50, 
    maxHP:50
};
```

Pick a `div id="hpbar"` and make it change in every hit, i.e. inside `hitMe`.

```
width = (enemy.hp*100)/(enemy.maxHP);
```

As for the colour goes you can change it as per the width values.

```
if (width<50){
    //set <div id="hpbar"> background to red with jQuery or DOM
}
else{
    //set <div id="hpbar"> background to blue with jQuery or DOM
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! You are a life saver. Thanks so much for your help and I hope that you have a wonderful day!